# Calculate mean value of 2D numpy arrays stored in a list

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

a:

```
[array([[0.10865657, 0.10638294, 0.10471012, 0.09508586, 0.09283491],
        [0.10892282, 0.10664408, 0.10496752, 0.09531553, 0.09305617],
        [0.11664   , 0.1143077 , 0.11259081, 0.1026154 , 0.10025029],
        [0.11626453, 0.11392252, 0.11219875, 0.10217754, 0.09980005]]),
 array([[0.04213751, 0.04178241, 0.04158858, 0.04331489, 0.04447674],
        [0.04213751, 0.04178241, 0.04158858, 0.04331489, 0.04447674],
        [0.04267657, 0.04255925, 0.04253528, 0.04520177, 0.04655534],
                         ...
```

I can do `a[0].mean` and I will get desired result. By I want to do it to the whole length of the `'a'` with for loop.

I have tried:

```
mean_all = []

for i in len(dist):
    mean = dist[i].mean
    mean_all.append(mean)
```

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: `for i in range(len(dist))`

Comment: Or more pythonic: `mean_all = [arr.mean() for arr in dist]`

Comment: tip1: `dist[i].mean` returns a function, tip2: you need `for i in range(len(dist))`. See my answer for a complete explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `dist[0].mean` returns a **function** and **NOT** the mean. You need, in general, `dist[0].mean()`.

**You can avoid the for loop easily using list comprehension:**

```
from numpy import array

dist = [array([[0.10865657, 0.10638294, 0.10471012, 0.09508586, 0.09283491],
               [0.10892282, 0.10664408, 0.10496752, 0.09531553, 0.09305617],
               [0.11664   , 0.1143077 , 0.11259081, 0.1026154 , 0.10025029],
               [0.11626453, 0.11392252, 0.11219875, 0.10217754, 0.09980005]]),
        array([[0.04213751, 0.04178241, 0.04158858, 0.04331489, 0.04447674],
               [0.04213751, 0.04178241, 0.04158858, 0.04331489, 0.04447674],
               [0.04267657, 0.04255925, 0.04253528, 0.04520177, 0.04655534]])]

mean_all = [dist[i].mean() for i in range(len(dist))]

print(mean_all)
[0.10536720549999998, 0.04307523133333334]
```

---

**If you really want to use the `for` loop, use this:**

```
mean_all = []
for i in range(len(dist)):
    mean = dist[i].mean()
    mean_all.append(mean)

print(mean_all)
[0.10536720549999998, 0.04307523133333334]
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the correct format of using range()

```
 for i in range(len(dist))
```